# cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: province laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code i use rajaongkir to get province

```
    $provinces = $this->getProvinces();

    $cities = isset(auth()->user()->province_id) ? $this->getCities(auth()->user()->province_id) : [];

    $user = auth()->user();



    return view('frontend.users.profile', compact('provinces', 'cities','user'));
```

Comment: The error message means that your server could not resolve the host name it is trying to make a request to, into an IP address. We can't really tell you why from the outside, might be a DNS issue, firewalling, etc. Talk to your server admin.

Comment: Looks like URL you need to access is https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter, so you can't resolve "api.rajaongkir.com" on your server.